# Is your luggage automatically transferred to the next flight if you enter the US on a precleared flight?

Tags: usa, luggage, connecting-flights, pre-clearance

I know that generally speaking everyone traveling to the US from abroad have to pick up their luggage, go through customs with it, and then check it in again for their next flight. But is this also necessary when traveling on a precleared flight from Canada?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my experience of flying from Vancouver, B.C. to the US I handed my luggage over basically to the TSA in Vancouver and picked it back up again when I reached my final destination in the US (which included a change of planes in Chicago)

Comment: I can confirm this always applies if having a Connection in the same booking.

Comment: Nitpick:  You gave your luggage to the CATSA in Vancouver (the Canadian government agency), not the TSA (the American government agency.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert CA`TSA` .. see .. it even says TSA in their name! But yeah, it's been a while and at ugly AM hours of the morning I wasn't really paying attention to whom I was giving my bags - just that I was following the correct queue.

Comment: I flew Vancouver to Calgary to US and I did not have to handle my luggage. What they did is show me a picture of my luggage on a screen and I had to verify that it was indeed my luggage. That was it.

Answer (score 8):

No, if arriving on a pre-cleared flight and having a connection in the same booking, you don't need to pick up luggage, as you'll already have cleared customs, which is the reason for you otherwise needing to pick up the luggage.